# Is it possible to show only a portion of CALayer ios?

Tags: ios, calayer, layer, quartz-2d, avcapturesession

In general,

Can you have a CALayer with a frame of (0,0,320,460) in an iPhone4 for example. And then decide that you want to only show the middle rectangle portion of that layer (150,220,20,20).

The idea here is to take a certain layer and then hide everything but that middle rectangle. I have tried with frames and bounds with no luck. I also looked into the CALayer methods to see if there is a method similar to the UIScrollView contentOffset. But no luck.

To make this more practical, take an AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer and then instead of displaying the whole layer, only show a middle rectangle - to be clear, this middle rectangle would not show the who layer but rather that specific middle rectangle of that preview layer.

Ho, Ho, Ho
Happy holidays.

Answer (score 0):

Use a CAShapeLayer as the mask for the layer you want to clip. CAShapeLayer has a path property that takes a CGPathRef.